# App Tracking Transparency permission is not prompting when trying to download the application in the App Store through the Apple Ad

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, app-transport-security, idfa

We Added the ATT(App Tracking Transparency) into our latest Application release, and everything worked fine except for one thing.

When our users try to download the application in the App Store through the Apple Ad specifically, the ATT permission isn't prompting and the data tracking permission is set to disabled by default.

When we try to download on the same device not through the Apple Ad, when we ran the application we see the ATT permission when we launch the application

If anyone has any input or value to add for this issue it will be very helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

iOS seems to cache the ATT permission for a while.

Try to restart your iOS device after the app was installed via "apple ads click" and then removed.
After the reboot of your iOS device and installing the app from app store the permission prompt should appear.

Comment: The ATT permission is not cached in the keychain, if you remove the application and install it you will always see the ATT permission. One of the first things we tried is to reboot the device which did not work.

Comment: This answer is correct. The ATT permission - once given - is cached. Only a restart of iPhone, and then installing it from AppStore will reset it.

Answer (score 2):

My permission appears again after I restart my device as @Jochen Holzer suggested.

**Note**: The permission always appear after uninstall > install in my colleague, but restarting the device is needed in my case. I assume that we have different version. Mine is *14.4* and hers is *14.1*

want to upvote his answer but I lack of point